# Insert all the lines of a file into another file between two patterns

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, regular-expression

file1 contents:

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

file2 contents:

```
[webservers]
[databases]
```

I want the file2 contents to look like: After adding all the lines, insert a new line.

```
[webservers]
1111
2222
3333
4444

[databases]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `r`ead command of `sed` to append a file after a pattern and the `s`ubstitute command to insert a newline:

```
sed -e '/\[webservers]/r file1' -e 's/\[databases]/\           
   &/' file2
```

Note that you need to escape the newline with a backslash as shown above to include it in the substitute pattern (the `&` stands for the whole match, so the match is replaced by itself, preceeded with a newline).

Also the `[` needs to be escaped to suppress its special meaning.

Comment: I am getting a `sed: -e expression #2, char 27: unterminated s' command` error.` Is there a space before `&`.  Doing this modification and putting the command in one line is fixing it: `sed -e '/\[heb_servers]/r file1' -e 's/\[kroger_servers]/\n\n&/' file2`

I ultimately want more than one file to be inserted into file2 and the single line command with absolute path is getting very long:

`sed -e '/\[webservers]/r /home/user/file1' -e 's/\[databases]/\n\n&/' -e '/\[databases]/r /home/user/file3' -e 's/\[local]/\n\n&/' /home/user/Downloads/file2 > /home/user/Downloads/hosts`

Comment: The second expression doesn't have 27 chars, so something went wrong on copying the command. Anyhow, you seem to have GNU `sed`, so you can use `\n` in the replacement as newline (note that this is not portable). This also means you can write everything into one expression: `sed -e '/\[webservers]/r /home/user/file1;s/\[databases]/\n\n&/;//r /home/user/file3;s/\[local]/\n\n&/'`. I also took advantege of repeating the last regexp by using an empty pattern.

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed with extended regex mode.

Sed command "a" can also be used here to append a trailing newline in the files being added.

```
sed -E \
  -e '/\[webservers]/r file1' \
  -e '/\[databases\]/r file3' \
  -e '/\[webservers]|\[databases]/a\
' \
file2 >hosts
```